# ASP.NET 5 Dependency Injection - Where is the Activate Attribute?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

ScottGu [showed](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5) a feature in vNext to use the Activate Attribute like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Activate]
    public TimeService TimeService { get; set; }
}
```

I'm on beta-8 and I can't seem to find this attribute, did it get removed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to using the renamed `[FromServices]` annotation on your properties, you can also utilize constructor injection:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private TimeService _timeService;

    public HomeController(TimeService timeService)
    {
        _timeService = timeService;
    }
}
```

I prefer this approach since ASP.NET 5 will fail to construct `HomeController` if it cannot find `TimeService`, rather than failing later with `timeService` being `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Found it...changed to [FromService]

Comment: You can accept your own answer by the way. This is allowed in StackOverflow.